# How to force Gboard to show suggestions in android app?

Tags: android, gboard

My Gboard settings in test device are just fine. Gboard shows suggestions in most of the apps that run on my device.

But when I run my own sample app, it doesn't show suggestions at all. I have a layout with EditText. I want suggestions to appear when user type something.

How to force Gboard to show suggestions in an android app? Is there any permission to add?

this problem is phone-specific. Keyboard showed suggestions in Samsung phone, but not on lenovo.